# Cannot find 'spec/support folder'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm trying Michael Hartl's rails guide, but I've faced a problem with Listing 5.9:

I haven't such directory!

What should I do?

[image]

Comment: Deep, no-no. I just needed the information about the directory. The guard input doesn't matter, I'm able to correct these errors :3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a support folder, create something you want to use as well as what you do in rails, and add it in `spec_helper.rb` like:

`Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }`

Comment: I'm really weird, I hate my inattention.

I have find some rows: 'We do this by creating both a spec/support directory and a utilities.rb file for RSpec utilities (Listing 5.29)'. 

Why I didn't see that before? :D 

Thank you xD